# How to pass commands noninteractively to running QEMU from the guest. QMP via telnet/SSH?

Tags: ssh, telnet, qemu

I'm running a virtualized Win8 (gaming) platform under Linux host. I use Synergy for keyboard and mouse sharing but I need to pass the usb devices occasionally. GPU is passed to the guest and I'm unable to access the QEMU monitor from the guest.

Issue is that I cannot release said devices without shutting down the guest. I'd like to pass `usb_add host:bus.addr` and `usb_del bus.addr` commands on the fly so I can attach and detach the devices as I need them. Beauty would be that I can keep the Synergy running all the time and only lock the devices to guest when I need them. I should add that Synergy's build-in locking via `lockCursorToScreen(toggle)` doesn't work reliably enough.

I'm not overly familiar with QMP but I can set up a telnet server to host with `-qmp tcp:192.168.0.10:4444,server,nowait` command line option. I don't know how to pass three commands via telnet and quit under windows.

Another option could be to set up a socket for the QEMU monitor with `-qmp unix:/path/to/socket,server`. Then I suppose I'd SSH to the host to interact with the monitor. I'm not sure how to automate that either. Run a shellscript on host from SSH command line?

SSH is more secure but I trust machines on this private network so that's not a huge issue.

TL;DR: I need a way to pass commands to running QEMU from guest. Telnet and socket (accessed possibly via SSH) are possible but don't know how to automate. Other sollutions welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem and post the answer here for posterity if someone else has the same issue. My host is linux and guest windows.

QEMU is launched with `-qmp tcp:192.168.0.10:4444,server,nowait` to enable telnet access to monitor. To bind the devices you want at lauch, add `-device usb-host,productid=12850,id="FancyKeyboard" -device usb-host,productid=64,id="FancyMouse"` to the commandline. Note that `-device,productid=` wants decimal id so you have to convert the hex you get from `lsusb` or similar to decimal first. the `,id=` part is to enable easy unbinding and can be any unique string.

To bind them at runtime from the host, I run a script I named _kvm_bind with

```
echo '{ "execute": "qmp_capabilities" }'
echo '{ "execute": "device_add", "arguments": { "driver": "usb-host","productid": "12850","id": "FancyKeyboard" }}'
echo '{ "execute": "device_add", "arguments": { "driver": "usb-host","productid": "64","id": "FancyMouse" }}'
```

And pipe the output to the monitor with [nmap's netcat](https://nmap.org/): 
`_kvm_bind|ncat 192.168.0.10 4444`
I'm running it from another script. ncat is smart and exits the telnet session automagically after EOF.

Binding from guest is similar and I installed nmap's commandline packet also to the guest. File _kvm_bind.bat looks as follows:

```
@echo off
echo { "execute": "qmp_capabilities" } & echo.
choice /T 1 /D y > nul
echo { "execute": "device_add", "arguments": { "driver": "usb-host","productid": "12850","id": "FancyKeyboard" }} & echo.
choice /T 1 /D y > nul
echo { "execute": "device_add", "arguments": { "driver": "usb-host","productid": "64","id": "FancyMouse" }} & echo.
```

`choice` is there to facilitate a second delay between the commands just in case. I'm unsure if `& echo.` is actually necessary, I didn't try that without it. It just outputs a blank lne ibetween the commands. It's likely not needed.

Piping is similar to linux version:

```
@echo off
_kvm_bind.bat|ncat 192.168.0.10 4444
```

Unbinding is similar to the binding, just exchange the second and third line to `device_del` and argument with the `id` you supplied when you bound it earlier:

```
echo '{ "execute": "qmp_capabilities" }'
echo '{ "execute": "device_del", "arguments": { "id":"FancyMouse" }}'
echo '{ "execute": "device_del", "arguments": { "id":"FancyKeyboard" }}'
```

Like I said in the question, I run Synergy to share the mouse and keyboard between guest and host and both of them have a monitor of their own. I don't need to shut down Synergy on binding and it works fine after unbinding. All in all, I'm happy with this for now.